# MongoDB aggregateRaw query - prisma - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I have a MongoDB collection called `detailLog` that contains records of user activities. I want to retrieve data for a **specific** user.

Here's my simplified current query:

```
const logs = await db.detailLog.aggregateRaw({
  pipeline: [
    {
       $lookup: {
         from: "Detail",
         localField: "detailId",
         foreignField: "id",
         as: "detail"
       }
     },
    {
      $match: { "detail.userId": userId }
    },
    .............
    ...............
    .................
  ]
});
```

Here is my simplified version of the Prisma schema for the relevant models:

```
model Detail{
id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
userId            String  @db.ObjectId
.............
...............
.................

detailLogs      DetailLog[]
}

model DetailLog {
id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
detailId String   @db.ObjectId
.............
...............
.................

detail Detail @relation(fields: [detailId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I'm working with Nextjs, Prisma and mongoDB and using the `aggregateRaw` function to run an aggregation query on one collection. However, I want to filter the results based on conditions from another collection, similar to a where clause. How can I achieve this in my aggregation query ?

I'm sure that there is data matching the `userId` and the `userId` is correct. If I remove the `$match` stage, I get data successfully.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: What's the value of `userId`? What is the output of that aggregation with just the `$lookup`?  Can you create and share a mongoplayground that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i solved my problem and added as an answer thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by revising my code as follows. Thanks to everyone.

```
const logs = await db.detailLog.aggregateRaw({
  pipeline: [
    {
       $lookup: {
         from: "Detail",
         localField: "detailId",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "detail"
       }
     },
    {
      $match: { "detail.userId": { '$oid': userId } }
    },
    .............
    ...............
    .................
  ]
});
```